# Run multiple sites from one IP in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

I have a box with Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7, and I'm using an ASP.NET app. 
I am trying to run multiple sites from one IP, but I can't access the sites from the outside. I can only access the Default website from outside but when I want to access the second one it does not work.

The second one should run on the `http://ip:81` and the default one is on 80.
They both run fine locally on the box and I have added a rule on the firewall to allow all inbound.

Comment: host headers are your friend

Comment: @Peter thanks Peter, How would that work?

Comment: @Peter, please add your comment as an answer, you saved my life

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***host headers are your friend***

This link might help you.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

You basically are going to run your sites on different ports and the tell IIS that http:// url1 maps to the site on port 80 and http:// url2 maps to port 81

Answer (score 39):

You can use the same port 80 for all the sites. It's all about the bindings. You need to bind each site to a different host name:

```
www.domain.example
site2.domain.example
www.anotherdomain.example
```

etc.

You can do this by specifying the binding when creating a site. Then make sure you have configured DNS records to point at the same IP.

You can also setup a catchall DNS entry for a domain and point it at the IP of the server, then every time you create a site you can simply pick a new subdomain name at it will work straight away.

Comment: I've been looking this for years. You can use other ports as well, but first the have to be opened at your router/firewall/pix.

Comment: but how do I point my domains to the IIS websites? i was using A records previously to point to different ports of the public IP address

Comment: just point them all at the same IP address and same port with your A records. The server will direct each request based on the domain used in the request.

Comment: Thanks Richard!

I wanted examples on how to do this and this link is very useful and may help anyone else looking for the same.

http://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/

Comment: If you don't have a DNS setup, and just want to test the bindings, you can add the bindings in: "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts". Then you able on the host machine to test the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

A TCP port number, an IP address, a host header these three are used to identify incoming http call processing and since first two is common now only you need to use host header which easily possible to done by command prompt and also with user interface of IIS.

Please read [this post here](http://woshub.com/run-multiple-websites-on-the-same-port-and-ip-address-on-iis/) to know whole process step by step