# Laravel - how to run multiple laravel application on single iis server

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I am currently running one website on laravel using IIS server. I want to run another application (website) on same time in same server. How can i run multiple application on same server together ?

I am using php could you please explain how can i do it in php

Comment: Create multiple sites in IIS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run multiple sites from one IP in IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489768/run-multiple-sites-from-one-ip-in-iis)

Answer (score 1):

You could use domain routes like

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'exampledomain.com'], function() {

your routes for this domain here.

});

Route::group(['domain' => 'exampledomain2.com'], function() {

your routes for this domain here.

});`
```