# How the MVC application get picked from the request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

We are going through the understanding of how the ASP.Net MVC request processed from start to end. During that we got the struck in the below point.

If we host multiple ASP.NET MVC applications in the same server with same pattern of Routes, how the web server picks the right MVC application to fulfill the request.

Explaining with internal working with example would be helpful to understand the concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read on hostheaders

Comment: Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: google it. you will find plenty of articles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run multiple sites from one IP in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489768/run-multiple-sites-from-one-ip-in-iis)

Comment: "If we host multiple ASP.NET MVC applications in the same server", in which way? The site/application structure on IIS determines how incoming requests are dispatched, and ASP.NET routing only takes effect once IIS finishes dispatching.